# MUI animation fades in but not out?

Tags: material-ui

https://mui.com/material-ui/api/fade/ < Not sure how to make the animation fade out aswell as in?

Any help is much appreciated.

```
{showSignUp && (
    <Fade in={showSignUp} timeout={4000}>
        <SalesSignUp />
    </Fade>
)}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's all you need to do!

```
{
    <Fade in={showSignUp} timeout={4000}>
        <SalesSignUp />
    </Fade>
}
```

Comment: I would not figure this out. Thanks